# How hoisting name resolution order works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

I came across a interesting [quiz](http://davidshariff.com/js-quiz/#q=5)

```
function bar() {
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    var foo = '11';
}
alert(typeof bar());
```

My interpretation is like this (Which is wrong according to console :) ):

```
var foo; // global variable
function bar(){
    function foo(){}
    var foo;  //  Here variable foo should override foo function 
    return foo; // (according to me foo should be variable with undefined value) What is going on here, How JavaScript resolve naming order ?
    foo = 10;
    foo = "11";
}
```

Here is a reference which I am reading [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

> In JavaScript, a name enters a scope in one of four basic ways:
>    1.Language-defined: All scopes are, by default, given the names this and  arguments.
>    2. Formal parameters: Functions can have named formal parameters, which are scoped to the body of that function.
>    3. Function declarations: These are of the form function foo() {}. 
>    4. Variable declarations: These take the form var foo;

He later quoted :

> The most important special case to keep in mind is name resolution order. Remember that there are four ways for names to enter a given scope. The order I listed them above is the order they are resolved in. In general, if a name has already been defined, it is never overridden by another property of the same name. This means that a function declaration takes priority over a variable declaration. This does not mean that an assignment to that name will not work, just that the declaration portion will be ignored.

Which is confusing for me, **Can anyone simplify this with reference to above example** ?
Main point I want to know :

- How variables without `var` inside a function hoisted ?
- Does variable overriding occurs during hoisting ?

Comment: http://scribu.net/blog/javascript-var-keyword-for-php-developers.html - "Inside a function, all undeclared variables are global. Only those declared with var are local."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets leave the function `foo` for the moment. Within a function, if a variable is declared anywhere inside that function, the declaration will be moved to the top of the function. So, it is actually evaluated like this

```
function bar() {
    var foo;
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    foo = '11';
}
```

But when you have a function declared by the same name, it will take precedence and it will be evaluated similar to this

```
function bar() {
    var foo = function() {};
    return foo;
    foo = 10;
    foo = '11';
}
```

That is why you are getting `function` in the alert box.

Comment: thanks, So you mean to say in function scope object  only one property will created with name 'foo' ?

Comment: @pandit Exactly... you will be assigning different objects to the same local variable at different point of times.

Answer (score 0):

Any variable without `var` inside a function becomes a global variable by default.

when you have a function declaration inside another function(like in your example), it gets hoisted first followed by the variable declarations.

examples to demonstrate variable overriding.

```
function bar() {
    var foo = 10;
    function foo() {}
    return foo;
}

bar(); //--> returns 10;

function bar() {
   var foo;
   function foo() {}
   return foo;
}

bar(); //--> returns the function object foo.
```

Comment: Thanks for entertaining, but I think thefourtheye answer is more accurate.