# Output of below code statements

Tags: javascript

```
var abc = function() {
    console.log(1);
}

function abc() {
    console.log(2);
}

abc();
```

I am expecting that it will console 2, but no it will console 1 because of
   function and variable hoisting.Anybody who want to make it more clear.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a question? Because it looks like you're just telling us how something works. Which, while noble, is not really within the scope of a Q&A site.

Comment: Have you tried it? This seems like the output would be trivial to verify

Comment: He seems to be asking why it outputs 1 rather than 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How hoisting name resolution order works in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988531/how-hoisting-name-resolution-order-works-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**var hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

the Key to understanding how scope in JavaScript works is understanding the concept of hoisting.

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are
>   processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere
>   in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means
>   that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared. This
>   behavior is called "hoisting", as it appears that the variable
>   declaration is moved to the top of the function or global code.

```
console.log("function hoisting:::: ",abc()); /* log = 2  we are calling the function(hoisting)*/

var abc = function() {
    console.log(1);
};
console.log("var:::: ",abc()); /* log = 1*/
function abc() {
    console.log(2);
}
abc(); /* log = 1*/
console.log("function:::: ",abc()); /* log = 1*/
```

***So in your case you are not calling the function***, to call the function log it on the top.

this is how the javascript engine interprets it

```
function abc() {
    console.log(2);
}

var abc;

abc = function() {
    console.log(1);
};

abc();
```

**[REF: JavaScript Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)**

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, a name enters a scope in one of four basic ways and the order of hoisting follows following order...

1. **Language-defined**: All scopes are, by default, given the names `this` and `arguments`
2. **Formal parameters**: Functions can have named formal parameters, which are scoped to the body of that function
3. **Function declarations**: These are of the form function `foo() {}`
4. **Variable declarations**: These take the form `var foo;`

*Reference: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html*

---

In your case the 1st function is *type 4* and the second function is *type 3*. Therefore the second function is hoisted first assigning the function reference to `abc`. And then the first function is hoisted reassigning the reference to `abc`. Your code is compiled in following order,

```
function abc() {
    console.log(2);
}

var abc;

abc = function() {
    console.log(1);
}

abc();
```

---

Note that only declarations are hoisted. Assignments are not hoisted.

```
var bar = 'test';
var foo = function(){/*foo 1*/};
var foo;
function foo(){/*foo 2*/} 
alert(foo);
```

will be complied in this order,

```
function foo(){/*foo 2*/}  //function declaration
var bar;  //variable declaration
var foo;  //variable declaration
bar = 'test';
foo = function(){/*foo 1*/};
alert(foo);
```

Comment: There is also the name of a named function expression, which isn't really any of these 4.

Comment: You mean `var foo = function foo(){}` ? It is case 4. isn't it? It is also treated same as variable declarations. @FelixKling

Comment: @FelixKling, you mean `var foo = function bar(){/* bar visible only here*/}`?

Comment: @FelixKling probably it could be considered as _type 2_

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply asking why the function `abc` isn't the one being executed despite it being declared most recently, it's because, In Javascript, functions are hoisted to the top of the current scope.

That means your code is morphed into something like the following:

```
function abc() { console.log(2); }
var abc = function() { console.log(1); }
abc();
```

That means, when it comes time to *call* `abc`, the "active" one is the one that logs `1`.

One of the best articles I ever found on this behaviour was [the one over at adequately good](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html).